# How to configure Visual Studio to not indent closing parenthesis on multiline function calls?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 RC (but this probably applies to 2015 and earlier versions as well). I'm working on a C# project where I have lots of code that looks like this:

```
Ast = new Ast(
    CallExpression("add")
    .AddChildren(
        NumberLiteral("4"),
        NumberLiteral("9")
    )
)
```

As you can see, the code takes a nested structure where closing parenthesis match the indentation of the original function call.

My problem is that when my cursor is in between the parentheses of a new function call:

```
Ast = new Ast([|])
```

and I hit Enter:

```
Ast = new Ast(
    [|])
```

there are an extra 4 spaces left behind the closing parens, not matching the original indentation. What I want is this:

```
Ast = new Ast(
[|])
```

Is there any way to configure VS to not add those extra spaces when hitting Enter in such a context? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to disable auto block indentation at all, or do you need to turn it off in this special case only?

Comment: @enkryptor Just this special case. I still want to indent when I have curly braces and press Enter, for example.

Comment: All the formatting options I see are for braces, and there is nothing specifically for parentheses other than spacing options.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Indenting->Block.
```

[image: valid XHTML]